# I need to print my data as structure using python

Tags: python

Data: [(Taru, 1234ABCD, 4536, EF32), (Aarul, 10045660, 4562, ABDE), (Vinay, 1254EFDC, 2587, AC42]in list form
output should be like (Tabular form)

Response: Taru  1234ABCD
                4536
                EF32

```
     Aarul  10045660   
            4562
            ABDE  

     Vinay  1254EFDC
            2587
            AC42
```

Please give your inputs to resolve this query.Thanks

Comment: Hard to understand the required output. Please provide your code so far.

Comment: @AkshayApte I have tried but it is not responding in that manner, we can consider Excel sheet as output file where we need to fill data column wise is given manner

Comment: @Melody , I am trying to print this data in informatic way like Taru: has these information Taru: (1234 ABCD EF1342) this data in column

Comment: if you show us your code, maby the question would be clearer and everyone can see that you have written something

Answer (score 2):

You can use this small script:

```
l = [['Taru', '12345678ABCDEF', 453678], ['Aarul', '10045660ABDECABF', 45621278]]

print("HEADER1       HEADER2             HEADER3")
for ele1,ele2,ele3 in l:
    print("{:<14}{:<11}{:13}".format(ele1,ele2,ele3))
```

Result:

```
HEADER1       HEADER2             HEADER3
Taru          12345678ABCDEF       453678
Aarul         10045660ABDECABF     45621278
```

Comment: Sir, output should be in tabular form but data inside the one main data like HEADER1 HEADER2 Taru 12343678 5678 ABCDEF thats mean Taru has these information, the name should be in first column and information should be in another column continuously

Comment: Based on what I did you should try to adapt it to your needs. Just give it a try and then update your code to show us what you tried. I am happy to help you out, but I am not a freelancer so I want to see you learn and try not just ask

Answer (score 0):

I think your main question is in how to split the list you got? This seems to be the pattern to do so

**EDIT** as per comment it was mainly formatting this is one possible sollution

```
entries = [["Taru", "1234ABCD", "4536", "EF32"], ["Aarul", "10045660", "4562", "ABDE"], ["Vinay", "1254EFDC", "2587", "AC42"]]

csv = 'Name,information\n'   
# this has split your array into the parts you want
for entry in entries:
    left = entry[0]
    for word in entry[1:]:
        print("{:<10}{:<10}".format(left,word))
        csv += str(left) + ',' + str(word) + '\n'
        left = ''
    print()

with open('output.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(csv)
```

OUPUT:

```
Taru      1234ABCD  
          4536      
          EF32      

Aarul     10045660  
          4562      
          ABDE      

Vinay     1254EFDC  
          2587      
          AC42
```

ouput.csv:

```
Name,information
Taru,1234ABCD
,4536
,EF32
Aarul,10045660
,4562
,ABDE
Vinay,1254EFDC
,2587
,AC42
```

Comment: If I may however take the freedom in noting that I have the input as strings if this gives an error for them being ints (the last one) by default you can parse it to string first usint str(entry[2])

Comment: I think you can combine zith the above answer to get the smooth tabular form

Comment: Sir, output should be in tabular form but data inside the one main data like      HEADER1       HEADER2        
           Taru                 12343678
                                   5678
                                  ABCDEF    thats mean Taru has these information, the name should be in first column and information should be in another column continuously

Comment: Thanks Sir, This data I need to save in CSV file, and whatever data is present in entry list need to access from text file

Comment: @Tarang to save to csv just build a csv string and save that to a file edited that in. And you're saying a file will be the input? Not a list? Would you be able to edit your question containing an example of the format of this input file has. If it's indeed the case you want to depart from an input file is the case?

Comment: csv += left + ',' + word + '\n' : it is not working with my code; giving error   
 csv += left + ' ' + word + '\t\n'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Like said we need a clear form of your input data. I assumed a two dimensional array containing strings. you getting an error on int oand str is as I've said above qoute:
_I have the input as strings if this gives an error for them being ints (the last one) by default you can parse it to string first usint str(entry[2])_

Addint str(int) will parse the int values to be strings. But onces again:
_[(Taru, 1234ABCD, 4536, EF32), (Aarul, 10045660, 4562, ABDE), (Vinay, 1254EFDC, 2587, AC42), ... etc_ is this exactly how your data looks like?, Edited the str parser in it @Tarang

Comment: I have edited it, it working fine as per present code, but once I open the csv file in excel file , whole data shown in once column only, whereas I need first element in first column and rest elements in 2nd column

Comment: I don't have excel installed. Are you certain you imported it to excel with ',' as the character to split columns? I tested it on google spreadsheet and it works potentially you want the ',' to be ';'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values 

As that is the European standard for csv files. But that should also be an option when in excel importing the file @Tarang

Comment: It is done now. It is printing accordingly. I have more implementation on this , so will discuss tomorrow

Comment: Thanks very much for your valuable guidance

Comment: @TarangJain I have a feeling you might not fully understand how stackoverflow works. It is not made to produce code for you but to ask code related questions. You can't really expect us to keep appending code till we've wrote an entire script for you. Python is not a hard language to learn. I would really advice just trying stuff searching for what exists. And asking code specific questions when you're stuck at some point

Comment: I understand your thought, before it I have some more lines in code and this is the mid of the part of that code. Thanks for your valuable response but I m writing my own code too.where I get stuck , I ask here.